# How i can make a change prefix command with database?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get guild id try if guild id == saved guild id at database, get prefix and change prefix to prefix at database.
Code:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix here, intents=intents)

@Bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    server = get_guild_or_false(guild.id)
    if server:
        pass
    else:
        aso = Aso(guild.id,".").save()
        
    db.commit()

@Bot.command()
async def change_prefix(ctx,prefix):
    objects = Aso.manager(db)
    guild_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    for guildcode in objects.all():
        guildcode_id = guildcode.id
        idcode = objects.get(guildcode_id)
        if guild_id == idcode.guild_id:
            idcode.prefix = prefix
            idcode.update()
            
    db.commit()
```

| id | guild_id | prefix |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id here | . |
| 2 | id here | ? |

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the question you want to have different prefixes for different guilds. Since this is just a discord.py tagged question, this is what you want:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    prefix = "?"  # Default prefix

    if not message.guild:
        return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)
    # DB fetch code here and replace the prefix variable
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)


intents = discord.Intents().all()

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=intents)
```

Comment: I cant understand your code.How i should use it?only copy paste?

Comment: @Aslan the intents and the Bot = is your code just add the top line to the main.py as well as get_prefix above the intents bit and it would work under the prefix `?` until you add the database operation to # DB fetch code here and replace the prefix variable